# Formula in excel that finds the highest number of each group of numbers in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to do a function that brings `TRUE` if it is the highest number of episode in each season. But I cannot use `If` functions, it should be conditional logic.

I would be grateful for help. This is a small example of the table. When the formula comes to season 1 episode 4, it needs to write `True` and in season 2 episode 24 and so on.

[image]

Comment: Can you add your attempt nonetheless?

Comment: right now i have this that i found on internet but its no good because it contains "if".
=IF(B2=B3,AND(C2=MAX($C$2:$C$237)),"TRUE")
and i tried this one but its not working on the last season (i got 10 , i put only a short example of the table in the question)
=(C3=1)

Comment: Try, looking at your sample data in `A1:B9` in `C2` the following: `=A2=MAXIFS(A$2:A$9,B$2:B$9,B2)`

Comment: My excel does not recognizes maxifs, I think I have old version of excel, do you know of a posibility without using maxifs?

Comment: If your data is ordered as you show, you could try: `=A2=LOOKUP(1,1/(B$2:B$9=B2),A$2:A$9)`

Comment: Yes it worked!! omg thank you very very much!!!!! (:

Comment: If you have your data unsorted you could use: `=$A2=LARGE(IF($B$2:$B$11=$B2,$A$2:$A$11),1)` in `C2`